# Ler arquivo e procurar palavra

Tags: ruby

Estou montando um *script* que vai abrir um arquivo de texto, jogar as palavras em um `array`,  e depois capturar o índice da palavra, até ai tudo bem eu consigo pegar o índice da palavra, porem eu preciso percorrer todo o `array` e se tiver a palavra repetida, preciso guardar todos os índices dessa palavra.

Arquivo teste.txt:

> a;b;c;a;d;a

Código:

```
file = File.open('teste.txt')
#fazendo um For Linha a Linha
file.each_line do |line|
        #Separando as palavras e convertendo para string      

        values = line.split(';').to_s()
        #capturando o index da palavra que seja igual a 'a'
        #idExc = Array[]
        idExc = values.index(/a/)

        puts values[idExc]

end
```

Ele só está capturando a primeira posição, porem eu tenho a letra `a` repetida, preciso guardar todos os índices referentes a `a`.

alguem tem ideia de como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar os métodos [`Array#each_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) e [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
values = [ "a", "b", "c", "a", "d" ]

p values.each_index.select { |i| values[i] == 'a' } #=> [0, 3]
```

Uma outra alternativa é iterar sobre a `array` com [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) conforme o número de elementos, e com [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) você faz a filtragem:

```
p values.size.times.select { |i| values[i] == 'a' } #=> [0, 3]
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/XFd3bz)</kbd>

No teu caso, você pode fazer assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

File.open('teste.txt').each_line do |line|
   line = line.strip
   values = line.split(';')

   p values.size.times.select { |i| values[i] == 'a' }              
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Se você quiser descobrir que letra que repete, dá para fazer assim:

`File.read("/tmp/teste.txt").chomp.
                            split(/;/).
                            reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |m, i| m[i] += 1; m }.
                            select { |k, v| v > 1 }`

Resultado:

`=> {"a"=>3}`